# Am I at risk of rabies? I touched a wet patch of grass but I didn't see any animal nearby

Tags: diseases, infections

There was no animal nearby and the grass was moist. The weather was hot. It was 35° C

Comment: wellcome to pets,this question do have an answer here https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21448/can-rabies-virus-survive-outside-host-on-grass-or-leaves-under-sunlight