# I got bitten by an almost 1 month puppy

Tags: dogs, behavior, medicines, diseases

I got bitten, on my nose, by an almost 1 month old puppy. I had a scratch. I bled for sometime and then stopped. I had applied alcohol to the spot.

I don't know whether the puppy has rabies or not.

Now my question is do I need to visit a doctor?

Also do I need to take the puppy to vet?

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question that no-one can answer for sure. It depends on so many information you didn't give in your question.

- Was the puppy a stray dog living on the streets? Then the chances of it having some kind of illness is higher.
- Was the puppy living with a family and being cared for? Then the chances of it having an illness are lower.
- Do you even live in an area where rabies is common? Rabies is an infection, a dog cannot have rabies out of thin air, it needs to be infected first. If you live in an area where rabies is seldom or doesn't exist in wild or stray animals, there's no chance the puppy could have it.

If it was a stray dog you should tell a doctor and let them decide what kind of medication (if any) you need. This is not only a matter of having rabies, but other infections as well.

Then you should not forget that puppies are playful, but not as dexterous as adult dogs. It might have wanted to play with you and accidently was too rough. You write that you had a scratch, so it's unlikely that the puppy actually wanted to bite you.

Rabies is a very dangerous illness, as detailed in [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/21448/12501). Infected animals often show strange behavior like staring straight ahead, being agressive for no reason or being very submissive for no reason. If the puppy behaved that way, you should get vaccinated as fast as possible.

The first noticable symptoms of a rabies infection are described as a tingling sensation that starts at the bite and slowly moves towards the head. As soon as you notice this tingling, it's too late to get vaccinated and medication doesn't work anymore.